# How to get TLB page size with cpuid

Tags: c++, assembly, cpuid

For Intel I use:

```
mov, eax, 2h
cpuid
```

it gives "descriptor decode value" - ok;

For AMD I use:

```
mov, eax, 80000005h
cpuid
```

It gives associativity and entries for 4MB in eax (4KB in ebx).

Here it is :

> EAX = FF30FF10 EBX = FF30FF20" 
>   FF - full assoc. data, 48d entries data, FF - full assoc. instr, 16d entries instr

So I have both 4KB and 4MB or what?

P.S. i`m right that TLB page and L1 cache - different things? Or maybe L1 instr. cache size is what I need?

Comment: So far as I understand, modern architectures offer both 4kB and 4MB.

Comment: It means if i just get correct output in EAX\EBX, i can say its 4MB\4KB?

Comment: My miss, amd docs says "for 2Mb or 4MB pages". "TLB cache sizes are 64 items" means if L1=64kb, so TLB page size=64*64kb?

Comment: Thx for help, but now i`m confused :) I have a tasks for TLB: 1)associativity, 2)entries, 3)size. How i should answer about size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [entry on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) may help you clear up some of the confusion on the different TLB sizes. It's under the heading "Multiple TLB's":

> For instance, Intel's Nehalem microarchitecture has a four-way set associative L1 DTLB with 64 entries for 4 KiB pages and 32 entries for 2/4 MiB pages, an L1 ITLB with 128 entries for 4 KiB pages using four-way associativity and 14 fully associative entries for 2/4 MiB pages (both parts of the ITLB divided statically between two threads)[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) and a unified 512-entry L2 TLB for 4 KiB pages,[2] both 4-way associative.[3]